# Trimmed values while parsing XML file

Tags: swift, xml-parsing

I need your help to sort my problem out, coding with Swift on XCode 14.1 :

When trying to parse an XML file, I noticed that most of values are not trimmed and appears in the XML file with some trailing spaces such as name="ABC     " and number of spaces is not always the same. It's randomely from 3 to 6 or 7 spaces.

For example, when I execute the following code :

```
let subIndexer = xml["Objects"]["Points"]["Point"]
.filterAll { elem, _ in elem.attribute(by: "name")!.text  == "ABC" }
```

...it doesn't find my element of course as it's "ABC           " in the XML.
How can I do ?

I thank you in advance !

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention language is Swift

Comment: Not really, sorry. I am a newbie and cannot figure out the way to implement it. I read also something about String.trimmingCharacters but cannot figure out either

Comment: Just implement the first answer in the linked question to `text`

Comment: I tried with : .filterAll { elem, _ in elem.attribute(by: "name")!.text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)   == "TOC" } but still cannot find my element. Did I implement wrongly the syntax ?

Comment: It looks right but I don’t know what filterAll does and if there is something else that is incorrect

Comment: Alright, thank you ! So if the syntax is correct, it means my problem is somewhere else. Appreciate your help all